# XSL v1.0 and XPath to Traverse Deep Nesting and Recursively Sum all Lines

Tags: xslt, xpath, recursion, xslt-1.0

I've been all over SO looking at other solutions, and tried various approaches, but still to no avial...

Here is the XML structure...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<query>
    <continueToken/>
    <results total="15">
        <result recordId="16672888">
            <columns>
                <column>
                    <field>AmountNU</field>
                    <LI_Amount><![CDATA[$4,000.00]]></LI_Amount>
                    <LI_Amount_display><![CDATA[$4,000.00]]></LI_Amount_display>
                </column>
            </columns>
        </result>
        <result recordId="16672889">
            <columns>
                <column>
                    <field>AmountNU</field>
                    <LI_Amount><![CDATA[$3,000.00]]></LI_Amount>
                    <LI_Amount_display><![CDATA[$3,000.00]]></LI_Amount_display>
                </column>
            </columns>
        </result>
        <result recordId="16672890">
            <columns>
                <column>
                    <field>AmountNU</field>
                    <LI_Amount><![CDATA[$2,000.00]]></LI_Amount>
                    <LI_Amount_display><![CDATA[$2,000.00]]></LI_Amount_display>
                </column>
            </columns>
        </result>
    </results>
</query>
```

And here is the XSL so far. This is only a small piece of a larger script, so you will see other things in that that are tangential to the current issue.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
xmlns:datetime="http://exslt.org/dates-and-times"
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
exclude-result-prefixes="datetime">
    <xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8" indent="no"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:call-template name="fixTheWidth" >
            <!-- This parameter is a Id for each group of records based on the result/@recordId attribute. This groups all records to the record ID-->
            <xsl:with-param name="resultIndex" select="//results/result[generate-id(.) = generate-id(key('recordID', @recordId)[1])]" />
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:template>

    <!--************************************************************************ 
        TEMPLATE: fixTheWidth
        PURPOSE: Where all the magic happens 
    *************************************************************************-->
    <xsl:template name="fixTheWidth" match="/results">
        <xsl:param name="resultIndex" /> <!-- A unique index based on grouping the records on the recordID -->

        <!-- more code here, uses $resultIndex -->

        <!-- Field Name: TOTAL INVOICE AMOUNT, Length = 9 (49-57), Format: numeric -->        
        <xsl:variable name="amount">
            <xsl:call-template name="total">
                <xsl:with-param name="sum" select="number(0)" />
                <xsl:with-param name="startLine" select="//LI_Amount_display" />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:variable>        
        <xsl:value-of select="$amount" />
    </xsl:template><!-- END of 'fixTheWidth' template -->

<!--****************************************************************************
    TEMPLATE: total
    PURPOSE: Add the total amount of all line items being processed.
*****************************************************************************-->
    <xsl:template name="total" >
        <xsl:param name="startLine"/>
        <xsl:param name="sum"/>
        <xsl:param name="newSum" select="$sum + number(translate(substring-after($startLine, '$'), ',', ''))"></xsl:param>

        <!-- TEST STUB -->
        <xsl:variable name="amount" select="number(translate(substring-after($startLine, '$'), ',', ''))" />
        <xsl:value-of select="number(translate(substring-after($startLine, '$'), ',', ''))" />
        <xsl:text> | </xsl:text>        
        <xsl:value-of select="$newSum + $amount" />
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text> 

        <xsl:for-each select="$startLine/ancestor::results/following-sibling::result/columns/column/LI_Amount_display">
            <!-- STUB -->
            <xsl:text> for each </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="number(translate(substring-after(., '$'), ',', ''))" />

            <!-- Recursively Sum --> 
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="position() = last()">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$newSum"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="$startLine/ancestor::results/following-sibling::result/columns/column/LI_Amount_display">
                <xsl:call-template name="total" >
                    <xsl:with-param name="startLine" select="." />
                    <xsl:with-param name="sum" select="$newSum" />
                </xsl:call-template>
                </xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The end result

`9000.00`

In other words, sum all the `<LI_Amount_display/>` nodes so that it can be output into a fixed width flat file.

The specific question lies around the XPath in the `for-each` loop in the "total" template. I haven't yet been able to see that I'm in that loop, thus, the `select` is in some way wrong... but how, well, that's why I'm here.

And finally, it must be with XSL version 1.0.

Let me know if you'd like further clarification.

Comment: Why should the end result be `11000.00` and not `9000.00`? As far as I can see, there are only 3 `LI_Amount_display` elements.

Comment: yes, apparently I learned to code in school, but not add... 9000.00 is what it should be... have edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I tend to go with the suggestion made by Mathias Müller, I wanted to show how you can do this using a recursive named template:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:call-template name="sum-nodes" >
        <xsl:with-param name="nodes" select="query/results/result/columns/column/LI_Amount_display" />
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="sum-nodes" >
    <xsl:param name="nodes"/>
    <xsl:param name="sum" select="0"/>
    <xsl:param name="newSum" select="$sum + translate($nodes[1], '$,', '')"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="count($nodes) > 1">
             <!-- recursive call --> 
            <xsl:call-template name="sum-nodes" >
                <xsl:with-param name="nodes" select="$nodes[position() > 1]" />
                <xsl:with-param name="sum" select="$newSum" />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="format-number($newSum, '#,##0.00')"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**:

```
9,000.00
```

Comment: Yes, I would love to tend towards the simplicity of Mathias solution. But I was unable to get it to work in the target system. Your solution did the trick.

Comment: In the event someone new to XSL ventures accross this, to finish off the code I added `format-number($newSum, '0.##')` in the `select` of the `<xsl:otherwise>...` statement to ouput the value to only two decimal places

Comment: Formatting the number as `'0.##'` limits the output value to **at most** two decimal places. In other words, it affects only values with three or more decimal places. It will have no effect in the above example. Use `'0.00'` to normalize **all** values to **exactly** two decimal places.

Answer (score 5):

I am not sure I understand your requirement. Why write such a complicated stylesheet when the end result should simply be a total amount of numbers? Also, it seems you are already familiar with the relevant EXSLT functions and with converting strings into numbers.

**Stylesheet**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common">
    <xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8" indent="no"/>

    <xsl:variable name="amounts">
        <xsl:for-each select="//LI_Amount_display">
            <amount>
                <xsl:value-of select="number(substring(translate(.,',',''),2))"/>
            </amount>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:value-of select="sum(exsl:node-set($amounts)/amount)"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
9000
```

Comment: the complexity is due to the tangential nature of the other code of I've taken out... trying to fit a square peg in a round hole unfortunately... inflexible constraints around a system that receives data in only one way.... AND (more importantly) XSL is something I picked up last month so I'm learning as I go

Comment: @RebelPhoenix Yes, I gathered you're trying to do something complicated. But saying that your code base is complex and that you're facing inflexible constraints does absolutely not help _me_ in helping you. So, again: Why can you not use a method as simple as the one above?

Comment: Because of how I've written the rest of the code, I have to output the value from within the `fixTheWidth` template. I ran this in my IDE and it works fine. But when I deploy to the target system, I get an exception: `javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: org.xml.sax.SAXException: xsl:template is not allowed in this position in the stylesheet!`

I tried a few things to get it to work but to  no avail.