# XSLT v1 - Calculate sum of discounts on invoice layout for pdf - NaN error

Tags: xml, xslt, sum, pdf-generation, xslt-1.0

I have three custom discounts, and I am trying to get the sum of the discounts so I can show on the pdf layout.

I need to programme this in XSL v1.0 as this is the what the CRM uses to generate the pdf templates. The full script is a combined document layout for all documents (quotes, orders, contracts and invoices) so I have only shown an extract.

In my test data there are three product lines, and at least one discount applies on each of the product lines.

```
LINE 1 Band Relief 302.5 Regional Discount 50% Price Discount 0%
LINE 2 Band Relief 10 Regional Discount 0% Price Discount 0%
LINE 3 Band Relief 0 Regional Discount 0% Price Discount 5%
```

I've tried to adapt Michael Hor257k's code ([XSL v1.0 and XPath to Traverse Deep Nesting and Recursively Sum all Lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27572683/xsl-v1-0-and-xpath-to-traverse-deep-nesting-and-recursively-sum-all-lines)) as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xslt:stylesheet xmlns:date="http://exslt.org/dates-and-times" xmlns:str="http://exslt.org/strings" xmlns:xslt="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:xf="http://www.ecrion.com/xf/1.0" xmlns:xc="http://www.ecrion.com/2008/xc" xmlns:xfd="http://www.ecrion.com/xfd/1.0" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" extension-element-prefixes="date str">
  <xslt:output indent="yes" encoding="utf-8"/>


<!-- ==== SUM NODES TEMPLATE ==== -->

  <xsl:template name="sum-nodes" >
    <xsl:param name="nodes"/>
    <xsl:param name="sum" select="0"/>
    <xsl:param name="newSum" select="$sum + translate($nodes[1], '$,', '')"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="count($nodes) > 1">
             <!-- recursive call --> 
            <xsl:call-template name="sum-nodes" >
                <xsl:with-param name="nodes" select="$nodes[position() > 1]" />
                <xsl:with-param name="sum" select="$newSum" />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="format-number($newSum, '#,##0.00')"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

and in the main template:

```
<xslt:template = "/">

<!-- === TESTING VARIABLES === -->

          <fo:block padding-top="0.45cm" font-size="9pt" padding-bottom="0cm">
            <xsl:for-each select = "/hash/order_line_items/order_line_item">
                <fo:block padding-top="0.45cm" font-size="9pt" padding-bottom="0cm">
                    <fo:inline>
                        Band Relief <xsl:value-of select="sum(cf_customer_invoice_line_item_band_relief/@amount)"/>
                        Regional Discount <xsl:value-of select="sum(additional_discount_1_percent)"/>
                        Price Discount <xsl:value-of select="sum(discount_percent)"/>
                    </fo:inline>
                </fo:block>
            </xsl:for-each> 
          </fo:block>

          <fo:block padding-top="0.45cm" font-size="9pt" padding-bottom="0cm">
            <fo:inline>

                <fo:inline> Band Total </fo:inline>
                <xsl:call-template name="sum-nodes" >
                    <xsl:with-param name="nodes" select="cf_customer_invoice_line_item_band_relief[@amount &gt; 0]" />
                </xsl:call-template>

                <fo:inline> Regional Total </fo:inline>
                <xsl:call-template name="sum-nodes" >
                    <xsl:with-param name="nodes" select="additional_discount_1_percent/@amount[@amount &gt; 0]" />
                </xsl:call-template>

                <fo:inline> Discount Total </fo:inline>
                <xsl:call-template name="sum-nodes" >
                    Discount Total <xsl:with-param name="nodes" select="discount_percent/@amount[@amount &gt; 0]" />
                </xsl:call-template>

        <!--        $regional_discount_1 <xsl:value-of select="$regional_discount_1"/> -->
        <!--        $price_discount <xsl:value-of select="$price_discount"/> -->
            </fo:inline>
          </fo:block>


</xslt:template>
```

however the sum only produces NaN results.

The discount fields are either currency or percentages (or null).

OUTPUT:

```
Band Relief 302.5 Regional Discount 50 Price Discount 0
Band Relief 10 Regional Discount 0 Price Discount 0
Band Relief 0 Regional Discount 0 Price Discount 5
Band Total NaN Regional Total NaN Discount Total NaN
```

EXPECTED RESULT:

```
Band Total £312.50 Regional Total 50% Discount Total 5%
```

I've been going round in circles for days trying to get this to work! Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**Update:**

I can't extract the full XML structure as its built in to the database, but for the invoice line items table it refers to:

```
                <xsl:for-each select="/hash/order_line_items/order_line_item[contains(./_preload_product_id, 'SHIPPING')=false()]">
              <fo:table-row>

                <fo:table-cell border-width="1pt" border-style="solid" border-color="rgb(0,0,0)" padding="2pt" text-align="right">
                  <xsl:attribute name="border-color">
                    <xsl:value-of select="/hash/text/Table_Border_Colour"/>
                  </xsl:attribute>
                  <fo:block font-size="8pt">
                    <fo:inline>
                      <xsl:value-of select="unit_quantity"/>
                    </fo:inline>
                  </fo:block>
                </fo:table-cell>
```

etc, so I presume it is /hash/order_line_items/order_line_item/

Update 2

As the data is embedded into the CRM, I can't extract the data as an XML file.

All I can do it export sample data from the database as a report:
If there is no band relief, there is no value posted. Band relief is set at Currency (but blank if no discount applied) while the other two discounts are set as percentages.

[csv of invoice data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e0sJR.png)

Can't seem to import the csv as a text field, so uploaded as image.

Hope this helps!

Comment: @Martin-Honnen - not sure why your comment has disappeared! However as requested, I've uploaded a csv of the data as I can't access the xml directly as this is in the CRM [link](workbooks.com}

Comment: Try using the [identity transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform#Using_XSLT) to get the source XML.

Comment: The only way to run code in the database is to generate xsl pdfs

Comment: When I run the identity transform code using the generate pdf button I got: > ERROR:  'org.apache.fop.fo.ValidationException: Error: First element must be the fo:root formatting object. Found (Namespace URI: "", Local Name: "hash") instead. Please make sure you're producing a valid XSL-FO document.'